# Are the both schemas equivalent?

Tags: xsd, xml-validation, xsd-validation

1.

```
<xsd:element name="tuple">
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##any" processContents="skip" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

2.

```
<xsd:element name="tuple"/>
```

Are the both above schemas equivalent?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO! They aren't same!

**In first schema:** element `<tuple>` can have 0 or more elements under it with/of any name, that is because you have added `<any>` tag with `minOccurs="0"` and `maxOccurs="Unbounded"` under `complexType` definition of element `tuple`

Also Since you have specified `processContents="skip"` under `<any>` it doesn't bother anything about its child elements..

Example:

```
<tuple>
  <foo>data</foo>
  <bar foobarattribute="foobardata">data</bar>
</tuple>
```

As you can see, though `foo` and `bar` and its attribute `foobarattribute` are not defined in XSD, it allows this XML as valid. **But it doesn't allow attribute under** `<tuple>`

> EDIT:

**Second schema:** 
It is as same as declaring the type as `anyType`

```
<xsd:element name="tuple" type="xs:anyType"/>
```

Which means it allows any element and any attribute under tuple.  The sample XML would be like:

```
<tuple foo="bar">
   <foobar attrb="value">data</foobar>
</tuple>
```

You can observe that unlike first sample XML, this has attribute under `<tuple>` as well.

One more important difference between two sample XSD code is:
In 1st code you are specifying processContents as "skip": Because of which XML processor does not attempt to validate any elements from the specified namespaces..

In the 2nd Code, for anyType, processContents would be "lax": because of which the XML processor tries to obtain the schema for the required namespaces and validate the elements.

Hope it helps..

Comment: Normally your answer should be downvoted; I hope though you'll correct it. While the first line is correct, the explanation is wrong on many levels. `tuple` in 2. is of [anyType](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#d0e9252) which means it can have any attributes, any elements, is mixed, and the processingContents is **lax**; in 1. tuple supports has **element only content**, **no attributes**, not mixed, and processingContents is **skip**.

Comment: @PetruGardea, thanks for validating my answer. I admit, I made blunder in defining case two. For some reason in Vis Studio, XSD validation is behaving different .. It doesn't treat 'no type' as 'anyType'.. I actually validated once before posting solution but should have checked with online validators as well. Thanks, I knew anyType, but I had been under false impression about `no type` so far. I have updated answer with processContents info as well.